# There is some problem occure in bootstrap ,I need 4 column in one row but its give me 1 column in every row

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am Using vue-cli ,vue-2 and bootstrap-4 ,have tried to make a project. I can't understand where is my fault.I need 4 column in 1 row but i get 1 column in 1 row.I also try col-sm-4 2nd template ,but still give me 1 column in 1 row.

1st template:

```
<template>
     <div>
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">

            <card-bar :items="items"></card-bar>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <card-bar2></card-bar2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </template>
```

2nd template:

```
   <template>
      <div>
       <div v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" class="card">
        <!-- <img :src="item.image" alt="o nno" class="card-img-top" /> -->
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{item.car_make}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
            content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    
    </template>

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JheQR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI4vJ.png
```

Comment: Consider reading the [relevant documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). Placing 4 `.col`s into a `.row` should do it. To make them wrap below a particular responsiveness breakpoint, make the `.col`s `.col-sm` or `.col-md`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the issue right.
You want 4 columns lined up in a row?

You need to actually write 4 separate columns, for example.

```
<!--Start of Row-->
<div class="row">

  <!--First Column-->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <card-bar :items="items"></card-bar>
  </div>

  <!--Second Column-->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <card-bar :items="items"></card-bar>
  </div>

  <!--Third Column-->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <card-bar :items="items"></card-bar>
  </div>

  <!--Fourth Column-->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <card-bar :items="items"></card-bar>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End of Row-->
```